# How to play audio in react native?

Tags: react-native

I am trying to play audio in react native. I tried to install `react-native-sound` but it did not install. I have installed the library `react-native-sound-player`. But when I press the play button it shows this error: `TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'RNSoundPlayer.playSoundFile')`. Here is my code:

```
import SoundPlayer from 'react-native-sound-player';

class myclass extends component {
    myfunction () {
        SoundPlayer.playSoundFile('../../assets/audio/filename', 'aac')
    }
    .....
    <Button onPress={() => this.myfunction() }>
        Play
    </Button>
}
```

Can anyone help. Thanks.

Comment: What is your react-native version on project? Did you link the library?

Comment: react-native: 0.61.4. Yes I linked the library.

Comment: Did you try to  play sound from url?  If you can means nothing wrong with library.

Comment: How to play sound from url? I did something like this: ```SoundPlayer.playSoundFile('https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/m/example.mp3')```. But the sound did not play in my project. But it's playing in the browser.

Comment: Try this: `SoundPlayer.playUrl('https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/m/example.mp3')`

Comment: It's not working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209662/discussion-between-ridvanaltun-and-boidurja-talukdar).

Answer (score 0):

SoundPlayer.playSoundFile is used to play sound files from the bundle. So you have to drag and drop the sound file to xcode, and then you can play it using

```
SoundPlayer.playSoundFile('filename', 'aac');
```

Remember to check "Copy items if needed" option and "Add to targets". 
On Android, put sound files in {project_root}/android/app/src/main/res/raw/. (Create the folder if it is not already available).

If you have to play a sound from a url use :

```
SoundPlayer.playUrl("http://SomeSound/File.mp3");
```

playUrl() can also be used to play sounds from the local documents folder, may be after downloading it to the app.

```
    SoundPlayer.playUrl(filePath);
```

For example if you downloaded the file using RNFetchBlob and saved it in the documents folder by specifying the location to RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs.DocumentDir, the code to play the file will be :

```
SoundPlayer.playUrl('file://'+res.path());
```

It took my some time to figure out that 'file://' had to be prefixed to the path. May be this will help someone now.